# error: 'res_ninit' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'res_init'?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, alpine-linux

I am trying to install an application from its source code in the alpine it says there is no `res_ninit`, `res_nsearch` and `res_nclose` but we can [see here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/res_nsend.3.html) that do exists in the Linux headers and I have already installed `apk add linux-headers`, how can I resolve this issue?

```
make install
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target save_linker_opts
[  2%] Built target save_linker_opts
[  2%] Built target build_protobuf
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target cdk_foundation
[  3%] Building CXX object cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/socket_detail.cc.o
/dep/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/foundation/socket_detail.cc: In function 'std::forward_list<cdk::foundation::connection::detail::Srv_host_detail> cdk::foundation::connection::detail::srv_list(const string&)':
/dep/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/foundation/socket_detail.cc:1097:3: error: 'res_ninit' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'res_init'?
 1097 |   res_ninit(&state);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
      |   res_init
/dep/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/foundation/socket_detail.cc:1107:13: error: 'res_nsearch' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'res_search'?
 1107 |   int res = res_nsearch(&state, hostname.c_str(), ns_c_in, ns_t_srv, query_buffer, sizeof (query_buffer) );
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |             res_search
/dep/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/foundation/socket_detail.cc:1143:3: error: 'res_nclose' was not declared in this scope
 1143 |   res_nclose(&state);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/build.make:146: cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/socket_detail.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1061: cdk/foundation/CMakeFiles/cdk_foundation.dir/all] Error 2
```

---

**Update:** I cat the header file `/usr/include/resolv.h` and we can see that function does not exists, so the question is how can I set up Linux header like ubuntu that can work in the alpine?

```cpp
#ifndef _RESOLV_H
#define _RESOLV_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/nameser.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#define MAXNS           3
#define MAXDFLSRCH      3
#define MAXDNSRCH       6
#define LOCALDOMAINPARTS    2

#define RES_TIMEOUT     5
#define MAXRESOLVSORT       10
#define RES_MAXNDOTS        15
#define RES_MAXRETRANS      30
#define RES_MAXRETRY        5
#define RES_DFLRETRY        2
#define RES_MAXTIME     65535

/* unused; purely for broken apps */
typedef struct __res_state {
    int retrans;
    int retry;
    unsigned long options;
    int nscount;
    struct sockaddr_in nsaddr_list[MAXNS];
# define nsaddr nsaddr_list[0]
    unsigned short id;
    char *dnsrch[MAXDNSRCH+1];
    char defdname[256];
    unsigned long pfcode;
    unsigned ndots:4;
    unsigned nsort:4;
    unsigned ipv6_unavail:1;
    unsigned unused:23;
    struct {
        struct in_addr addr;
        uint32_t mask;
    } sort_list[MAXRESOLVSORT];
    void *qhook;
    void *rhook;
    int res_h_errno;
    int _vcsock;
    unsigned _flags;
    union {
        char pad[52];
        struct {
            uint16_t        nscount;
            uint16_t        nsmap[MAXNS];
            int         nssocks[MAXNS];
            uint16_t        nscount6;
            uint16_t        nsinit;
            struct sockaddr_in6 *nsaddrs[MAXNS];
            unsigned int        _initstamp[2];
        } _ext;
    } _u;
} *res_state;

#define __RES   19960801

#ifndef _PATH_RESCONF
#define _PATH_RESCONF        "/etc/resolv.conf"
#endif

struct res_sym {
    int number;
    char *name;
    char *humanname;
};

#define RES_F_VC    0x00000001
#define RES_F_CONN  0x00000002
#define RES_F_EDNS0ERR  0x00000004

#define RES_EXHAUSTIVE  0x00000001

#define RES_INIT    0x00000001
#define RES_DEBUG   0x00000002
#define RES_AAONLY  0x00000004
#define RES_USEVC   0x00000008
#define RES_PRIMARY 0x00000010
#define RES_IGNTC   0x00000020
#define RES_RECURSE 0x00000040
#define RES_DEFNAMES    0x00000080
#define RES_STAYOPEN    0x00000100
#define RES_DNSRCH  0x00000200
#define RES_INSECURE1   0x00000400
#define RES_INSECURE2   0x00000800
#define RES_NOALIASES   0x00001000
#define RES_USE_INET6   0x00002000
#define RES_ROTATE  0x00004000
#define RES_NOCHECKNAME 0x00008000
#define RES_KEEPTSIG    0x00010000
#define RES_BLAST   0x00020000
#define RES_USEBSTRING  0x00040000
#define RES_NOIP6DOTINT 0x00080000
#define RES_USE_EDNS0   0x00100000
#define RES_SNGLKUP 0x00200000
#define RES_SNGLKUPREOP 0x00400000
#define RES_USE_DNSSEC  0x00800000

#define RES_DEFAULT (RES_RECURSE|RES_DEFNAMES|RES_DNSRCH|RES_NOIP6DOTINT)

#define RES_PRF_STATS   0x00000001
#define RES_PRF_UPDATE  0x00000002
#define RES_PRF_CLASS   0x00000004
#define RES_PRF_CMD 0x00000008
#define RES_PRF_QUES    0x00000010
#define RES_PRF_ANS 0x00000020
#define RES_PRF_AUTH    0x00000040
#define RES_PRF_ADD 0x00000080
#define RES_PRF_HEAD1   0x00000100
#define RES_PRF_HEAD2   0x00000200
#define RES_PRF_TTLID   0x00000400
#define RES_PRF_HEADX   0x00000800
#define RES_PRF_QUERY   0x00001000
#define RES_PRF_REPLY   0x00002000
#define RES_PRF_INIT    0x00004000

struct __res_state *__res_state(void);
#define _res (*__res_state())

int res_init(void);
int res_query(const char *, int, int, unsigned char *, int);
int res_querydomain(const char *, const char *, int, int, unsigned char *, int);
int res_search(const char *, int, int, unsigned char *, int);
int res_mkquery(int, const char *, int, int, const unsigned char *, int, const unsigned char*, unsigned char *, int);
int res_send(const unsigned char *, int, unsigned char *, int);
int dn_comp(const char *, unsigned char *, int, unsigned char **, unsigned char **);
int dn_expand(const unsigned char *, const unsigned char *, const unsigned char *, char *, int);
int dn_skipname(const unsigned char *, const unsigned char *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: Is there no comment on top of the file?? `how can I set up Linux header like ubuntu that can work in the alpine?` You want to "setup" a header file? What do you mean by that? Header files exists, they are not "setup".

Comment: @KamilCuk I just copy/pasted the entire file. we install the `linux-headers` to get access to Linux specific headers, so basically they don't exist by default. apparently the Alpine's `<resolv.h>` headers are not the same as the official Linux header. My guess is we might be able to get rid of the missing functions by overriding the file meaning we need to install the right package in the alpine _if there is any_!

Comment: header files are only for compiling. To run the program you must also install the matching library.  That's why you can't just copy the Ubuntu header.

Comment: @stark maybe I couldn't explain what was in my mind with the right words... I am not a newbie. so there is no need for newbie-talk ;)

Comment: Thank you for explaing that. I am very relieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in the Linux headers

Linux is generally/colloquially the name of all unix-ish operating systems with a Linux kernel, but specifically, Linux refers to the Linux kernel tiself. The resolve headers are not part of Linux kernel. `linux-headers` install headers needed to compile Linux kernel modules. It's unrelated.

The mentioned resolver headers are implemented inside glibc GNU C library. Alpine distribution uses musl implementation of C standard library, not glibc.

> how can I resolve this issue?

One of:

- you can implement `res_ninit` and relevant function that depend on musl and use that implementation when compiling the application
- patch mysql-connector yourself to be compilable with musl
- compile/install glibc to your system and compile mysql-connector against it
- do not use alpine for programs that require glibc and use only glibc-compatibile Linux distribution
- notify mysql-connector developers about the issue and financially support them so they will fix the issue

Comment: I prefer the #3, I have tried to install `apk add libc6-compat` but the content of the file didn't change.

Comment: Well, I would suggest #4. The whole point of alpine is that it uses musl - when installing glibc, you might better use somethign with glibc, no point. `the content of the file didn't change.` The part `compile mysql-connector against it` is also important. I have no idea how to configure application, I also do not know if `libc6-compat` contains _all_ the needed implementations, my guess would be that most probably is does not.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I need to go back and use the ubuntu image for the base, I wanted to use the alpine because it was lighter, but I guess that's not an option anymore :/